# React Spring boot react deployment issue

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot

need to understand how to proxy is set in react so that authentication can be performed in spring boot application. Also, how we can deploy the basic app on clustered environment.

need to understand how to proxy is set in react so that authentication can be performed in spring boot application. Also, how we can deploy the basic app on clustered environment.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.okta.developer</groupId>
    <artifactId>jugtours</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>jugtours</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <frontend-maven-plugin.version>1.6</frontend-maven-plugin.version>
        <node.version>v10.13.0</node.version>
        <yarn.version>v1.12.1</yarn.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-resources</id>
                                <phase>process-classes</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/static</outputDirectory>
                                    <resources>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>app/build</directory>
                                        </resource>
                                    </resources>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <workingDirectory>app</workingDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>install node</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>install-node-and-yarn</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                                    <yarnVersion>${yarn.version}</yarnVersion>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>yarn install</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>yarn</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>yarn test</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>yarn</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>test</arguments>
                                    <environmentVariables>
                                        <CI>true</CI>
                                    </environmentVariables>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>yarn build</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>yarn</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>build</arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>prod</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: What exactly is the prblem? What in this code is causing doubts? plaese be more specific and show what research have you done.

Answer (score 0):

4.0.0

```
<groupId>e.the.awesome</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-react-combo-app</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>spring-react-combo-app</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot and React</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>basic-frontend-app</workingDirectory>
                <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v8.9.4</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>5.6.0</npmVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>npm run build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>run build</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/classes/public">
                                <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/basic-frontend-app/build"/>
                            </copy>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.heroku</groupId>
                                <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                <version>9.0.30.0</version>
                                <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```